# How do I get an MCE IR remote to work with mpv?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 20.04, mpv-media-player

I have an old Dell MCE remote which I would like to repurpose for remote controlling `mpv`.

> [image: Dell MCE Remote XPS]

I am running Kubuntu 20.04, with `mpv` version 0.32 and `ir-keytable` 1.18.0-2build1. I have set up `ir-keytable` with `rc6_mce.toml` in `/etc/rc_keymaps`. When I test the remote **with** `ir-keytable -t`, **every key of the remote is correctly reported**, 45 keys in total.

However, when I run `mpv --input-test --force-window --idle` and press the keys again, barely a handful of keys registers:

```
 input: Key DEL is bound to:
 input: 1.  'script-binding osc/visibility' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key DEL is bound to:
 input: 1.  'script-binding osc/visibility' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key ENTER is bound to:
 input: 1.  'playlist-next' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key RIGHT is bound to:
 input: 1.  'seek  5' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key LEFT is bound to:
 input: 1.  'seek -5' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key DOWN is bound to:
 input: 1.  'seek -60' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key UP is bound to:
 input: 1.  'seek  60' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key 0x21ff56 is bound to:
 input: (nothing)
 input: Key 0x21ff56 is bound to:
 input: (nothing)
 input: Key 0x21ff32 is bound to:
 input: (nothing)
 input: Key PLAY is bound to:
 input: 1.  'cycle pause' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key FORWARD is bound to:
 input: 1.  'seek 60' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key REWIND is bound to:
 input: 1.  'seek -60' in <builtin>:1 (default)
 input: Key CANCEL is bound to:
 input: (nothing)
 input: Key 0x21ff1c is bound to:
 input: (nothing)
 input: Key PAUSE is bound to:
 input: 1.  'cycle pause' in <builtin>:1 (default)
```

My `input.conf` shouldn't contain anything which interferes, it is not referenced in the input test either. For the sake of completeness:

`input.conf`

```
Shift+RIGHT frame-step
Shift+LEFT frame-back-step
R add sub-scale +0.1
Y add sub-scale -0.1
H seek -65
h seek 65
v cycle deband
a cycle audio
s cycle sub
i cycle interpolation
t script-message-to seek_to toggle-seeker
+ add audio-delay 0.010
- add audio-delay -0.010
F1 add sub-delay -0.1
F2 add sub-delay +0.1
F4 cycle-values video-aspect-override "16:9" "4:3" "2.35:1" "-1"
```

Furthermore, some keys like `SLEEP`, `VOLUME_UP`, `VOLUME_DOWN` and `MUTE` pass right through to the OS and do their thing, which can be seen by the KDE popup. (`SLEEP` is just logging me out, though).

To sum it up: 4 keys on the remote act on the system even when trying to input test, 4 keys just show a keycode (different to `ir-keytable`) even though `ir-keytable` recognized them perfectly, and just 11 keys are registered in `mpv`'s input test. One key (`DEL`) seems to be assigned to two keys on the remote.

Also, when I try to add unassigned keys from the remote to `input.conf`, running `mpv` gives errors:

```
[input] Unknown key 'KEY_NEXT' at /etc/mpv/input.conf:17
[input] Unknown key 'KEY_PREVIOUS' at /etc/mpv/input.conf:18
```

There seems to be something missing to let `mpv` recognize the IR remote which is correctly set up in `ir-keytable`.

What do I need to do to have proper assignments of keys to `mpv` actions?

Comment: @Skynet that was a configuration file and should be code formatted. We don't need key codes in configuration file to keyboard formatted.

Comment: @muru ok got the point sorry for misunderstanding, thanks for explanation :)

Comment: @Skynet no worries, I just didn't want to undo most of your work without saying anything.